# Automatic .toString() when calling a method?

Tags: java

I got the code of a former employee. There are many calls to methods like:

```
foo(val,...);
```

where

```
void foo(String s,...) {
  ...
}
```

and val is an int.

Of course, I get an error.

As a workaround I pass ""+val to foo. I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

depending on the different types that are supposed to be passed as parameter, you could either accept an object and call .toString()

```
void foo(Object o){
   String s=o.toString();
   ...
}
```

or overload foo for specific types

```
void foo(String s) {
  ...
}

void foo(int i){
    foo(Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use the Object parameter approach.

Answer (score 3):

String.valueOf(val) is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Without modifying the method definition, that's the quickest and easiest way to do it.